# Laravel - Pluck multiple columns

Tags: laravel

I need to pluck two columns `name` and `score` from my table `corporate_objectives` and put it in my graph chart. I'm having two different behavior and I can't seem to get my desired result.

**1st code**

```
$getNameAndScore = CorporateObjective::pluck('name');

foreach($getNameAndScore as $key => $item) {
  $corporateObjective[] = [$item, '('.$key.'%)'];
}
```

**Result:**

```
    "xAxis": [
    [
      "PEOPLE DEVELOPMENT",
      "(0%)"
    ],
    [
      "OPTIMUM SYSTEMS AND PROCESSES",
      "(1%)"
    ],
    [
      "CUSTOMER MANAGEMENT",
      "(2%)"
    ],
    [
      "REVENUE GROWTH",
      "(3%)"
    ]
  ],
```

**2nd code**

```
$getNameAndScore = CorporateObjective::pluck('name', 'score');

foreach($getNameAndScore as $key => $item) {
  $corporateObjective[] = [$item, '('.$key.'%)'];
}
```

**Result:**

```
  "xAxis": [
    [
      "REVENUE GROWTH",
      "(25%)"
    ]
  ],
```

I'm getting all the correct `name` but the incorrect `score` in my first code. On my second code, I'm getting the correct `name` and `score` but all data is not being pulled out. I wanted to achieve the first code with all the correct `score` from the second code.

**EDIT:**
This is how my database looks like

```
id | name                          | score
1    PEOPLE DEVELOPMENT              25
2    OPTIMUM SYSTEMS AND PROCESSES   25
3    CUSTOMER MANAGEMENT             25
4    REVENUE GROWTH                  25
```

Is there another way other than `pluck`? It seems like `pluck` merges / filters all data with the same value.

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/collections#method-pluck What does `$getNameAndScore->all()` return?

Comment: Same output for first and second code. I think I get it, all the other four all have the same 25% `score` so all scores are merged. Is there a way so not merge them in `pluck`? I'll edit my question.

Answer (score 1):

This is the correct output of your code. There is no problem here

```
$getNameAndScore = CorporateObjective::pluck('name', 'score');

foreach($getNameAndScore as $key => $item) {
    $corporateObjective[] = [$item, '('.$key.'%)'];
}
```

How does work `pluck` here is description

> If duplicate keys exist, the last matching element will be inserted into the plucked collection:

```
$collection = collect([
    ['brand' => 'Tesla',  'color' => 'red'],
    ['brand' => 'Pagani', 'color' => 'white'],
    ['brand' => 'Tesla',  'color' => 'black'],
    ['brand' => 'Pagani', 'color' => 'orange'],
]);

$plucked = $collection->pluck('color', 'brand');

$plucked->all();

// ['Tesla' => 'black', 'Pagani' => 'orange']
```

[Details in here](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/collections#method-pluck)

Answer (score 0):

So I just made an alternative way of doing it and it might help other people. If there is a more proper way or cleaner way of doing it, please feel free to correct my answer.

```
$getNameAndScore = CorporateObjective::pluck('name');

foreach($getNameAndScore as $item) {
  $key = CorporateObjective::where('name', $item)->value('score');
  $corporateObjective[] = [$item, '('.$key.'%)'];
}
return response()->json([
  'xAxis' => $corporateObjective,
]);
```

**Result**

```
 "xAxis": [
    [
      "PEOPLE DEVELOPMENT",
      "(25%)"
    ],
    [
      "OPTIMUM SYSTEMS AND PROCESSES",
      "(1%)" // I changed the value in the database and it works
    ],
    [
      "CUSTOMER MANAGEMENT",
      "(22%)" // I changed the value in the database and it works
    ],
    [
      "REVENUE GROWTH",
      "(25%)"
    ]
  ],
```